# Обрезка изображения из Галереи

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, изображения

Пытаюсь осуществить обрезку изображений в своем приложении. Нашел код, который обрезает фото, сделанные тут же на камеру, но при попытке дописать этот код, добавив возможность обрезки изображений при выборе из Галереи, я сталкиваюсь с ошибкой:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=0, data=null} to activity {....MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException в строке кода "Bundle extras = data.getExtras();"
```

Мой код Активити:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ImageView imVCature_pic;
Button btnCapture;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initializeControls();
}

private void initializeControls() {
    imVCature_pic=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imVCature_pic);
    btnCapture=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
    Button buttonGallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_select_gallery);
    btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /* create an instance of intent
             * pass action android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE
             * as argument to launch camera
             */
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            /*create instance of File with name img.jpg*/
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "img.jpg");
            /*put uri as extra in intent object*/
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
            /*start activity for result pass intent as argument and request code */
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    });

    buttonGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent intent2 = new Intent();

            intent2.setType("image/*");
            intent2.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            File file2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "img2.jpg");
            /*put uri as extra in intent object*/
            intent2.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file2));
            /*start activity for result pass intent as argument and request code */
            startActivityForResult(intent2, 3);
        }} );
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //if request code is same we pass as argument in startActivityForResult
    if(requestCode==1){
        //create instance of File with same name we created before to get image from storage
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "img.jpg");
        //Crop the captured image using an other intent
        try {
            /*the user's device may not support cropping*/
            cropCapturedImage(Uri.fromFile(file));
        }
        catch(ActivityNotFoundException aNFE){
            //display an error message if user device doesn't support
            String errorMessage = "Sorry - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
    if(requestCode==2){
        //Create an instance of bundle and get the returned data
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        //get the cropped bitmap from extras
        Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
        //set image bitmap to image view
        imVCature_pic.setImageBitmap(thePic);
    }
    if(requestCode==3){
        //create instance of File with same name we created before to get image from storage
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "img.jpg");
        //Crop the captured image using an other intent
        try {
            /*the user's device may not support cropping*/
            cropCapturedImage(Uri.fromFile(file));
        }
        catch(ActivityNotFoundException aNFE){
            //display an error message if user device doesn't support
            String errorMessage = "Sorry - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
}
//create helping method cropCapturedImage(Uri picUri)
public void cropCapturedImage(Uri picUri){
    //call the standard crop action intent
    Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    //indicate image type and Uri of image
    cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
    //set crop properties
    cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    //indicate aspect of desired crop
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 256);
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 256);
    //indicate output X and Y
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
    //retrieve data on return
    cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
    startActivityForResult(cropIntent, 2);
}
```

}

Где и что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: На каком моменте приложение падает с данной ошибкой?

Comment: @AdamLuisSean , я нажимаю на кнопку "открыть Галерею", выбираю фото, проходит примерно 0,5 секунды, и приложение крашится. В коде это момент, который я указал в вопросе выше, т.е. строка "Bundle extras = data.getExtras();"